# Javascript Array.prototype.find second argument thisArg not working

Tags: javascript

I was reading a JavaScript book and found this code about how to use `arr.find(callback[, thisArg])`

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = Person.nextId++;
    }
}

Person.nextId = 0;

const jamie = new Person("Jamie"),
      juliet = new Person("Juliet"),
      peter = new Person("Peter"),
      jay = new Person("Jay");
const arr = [jamie, juliet, peter, jay];

// option 2: using "this" arg:
arr.find(p => p.id === this.id, juliet); // returns juliet object
```

I cannot get the desired result. Everytime the `find()` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `arrow` functions, which preserve lexical scoping. The `this` variable inside your arrow function represents `window` and not the `juliet` argument you have passed.

To rectify this, you can simply use `function` to create new scope and pass `juliet` as `this`.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = Person.nextId++;
    }
}

Person.nextId = 0;

const jamie = new Person("Jamie"),
      juliet = new Person("Juliet"),
      peter = new Person("Peter"),
      jay = new Person("Jay");
const arr = [jamie, juliet, peter, jay];

// option 2: using "this" arg:
let a = arr.find(function(p) {
  return p.id === this.id;
}, juliet); 

console.log(a);
```